# How to increment a string in python

Tags: python, string

I was trying this code:

```
str = input("Enter the string:")
num = input("By how much you want to increment:")
x = int(str) + num
print(char(num))
```

but this throws a traceback, What will be the correct code and what if the person enters (z + 1) i.e. how will the code be fixed around only the 26 alphabets.
Thank you

Comment: `num = int(input("By how much you want to increment:"))`

Comment: and dont use `str` for a variable name. bcoz its a reserved word in python which stants for `type string`

Comment: Do you mean that if you take 'a', increment by 1, you get 'b'? In that case you weel need `chr` and `ord`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ord` to get ascii of them and `chr` to get back the value using ascii value

```
def inc_letter(char, inc):
    
    start_char = ord('a') if char.islower() else ord('A') 
    start = ord(char) - start_char
    offset = ((start + inc) % 26) + start_char
    result = chr(offset)
    return result
```

---

```
str_ = input("Enter the string:")
num = int(input("By how much you want to increment:"))
inc_letter(str_, num)
```

---

**Result:**

```
Enter the string:Z
By how much you want to increment:12
'L'
```